# Storing information from a string between two sub-strings into an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Sorry, question was a bit awkward to word.

I was wondering how I would be able to store some information extracted from two sub-strings into an array.

Here's an example:

```
>>> print ( Messages )

<MESSAGE>How's it going</MESSAGE>
<MESSAGE>Go to bed</MESSAGE>

>>> print ( Message[0] )

How's it going

>>> print ( Message[1] )

Go to bed
```

Comment: Is this XML ? If yes, you should use Python XML libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to extract the substring between the `MESSAGE` tags and append them to a list.

```
import re
messages = """
<MESSAGE>How's it going</MESSAGE>
<MESSAGE>Go to bed</MESSAGE>
"""

data = []
matches = re.finditer(r'<MESSAGE>(.*?)</MESSAGE>', messages)

for x in matches:
    data.append(x.group(1))

print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

Messages= "<MESSAGE>How's it going</MESSAGE>" \
'<MESSAGE>Go to bed</MESSAGE>'

#Using regex to find all the messages
Message=list(re.findall(r'<MESSAGE>(.*?)</MESSAGE>',Messages))

print(Message)
```

The above should return
`["How's it going", 'Go to bed']`

---

**Regex Explain**

```
<MESSAGE>   #what the result should precede by
(           #Group start which is returned by findall
.*          #Match multiple characters with the given conditions
?           #Match as minimal set as possible, otherwise it would be greedy and match you across many tags
)           #Group  end which is returned by findall
</MESSAGE>  #What the group should be followed by
```